# Select file path on the first selection

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

What should I change in this code?

When I open the dialog box, I want to choose the file only once, not two times to choose the file path. I have to choose the file path twice to display it in the textbox with that code.

```
Private Sub BttImportY_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BttImportY.Click
    TxtNumberListScan.Clear()
    ' Call ShowDialog.
    Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    ' Test result.
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        ' Get the file name.
        Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        ' Read in text.
        Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(path)
        Dim lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(path).Length
        TxtCheckDraws.Text = TBIntDLX.Text - 1
        TxtNumberListScan.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
        TxtCheckL.Text = lineCount
        TxtCheckList.Text = TxtCheckL.Text - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just, remove this line:

```
Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
```